# Login control doesn't redirect the user to another page

Tags: asp.net

I am developing VS2010. this is my problem:I have a Form that authenticate user and then redirect them to another page .the redirection is not working If I write username and password system say nothing and two textboxes being empty :

here is a part of my login control

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
        RenderOuterTable="false" DestinationPageUrl="~/verwaltung.aspx" MembershipProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
```

and also in my web.config I have:

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know the login was successful? Do you have a `LoginStatus` control on the page?

Comment: yes I have,but that doesn't show me the current user

Comment: That means your login is not working. Have you set your web.config to use the authentication mode to forms?

Comment: but if a user registet then I can see thenon loginstatus,Which settings should I perform in web.config?

Comment: I have this part of code in my web.config **<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/verwaltung.aspx"/>
    </authentication>**

Comment: Provide your code behind code as well...may be this will help you. http://forums.asp.net/t/949993.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

You said your codebehind is empty, actually when you use login control you need to write login handler like this.

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Online"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Account WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", conn);
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            SqlParameter Username = new SqlParameter();
            Username.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            Username.ParameterName = "Username";
            Username.Value = Login1.UserName.ToString().ToLower().Trim();

            SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter();
            Password.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            Password.ParameterName = "Password";
            Password.Value = Login1.Password;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(Username);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Password);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    e.Authenticated = true;//User was found in the database
                    Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName.ToString();
                    Session["Name"] = rdr[0].ToString() + " " + (rdr[1].ToString() == null ? "" : rdr[1]);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
            if (e.Authenticated)
                Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");//Do whatever needs to be done when user gets authenticated
            }
        }
```